# Create new column based on partial match with another column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, string-matching

I want to create a new column for a dataframe, using partial matches in another column. The problem is that my values are only partial matches, the suffix _3p, or _5p at the end of the names only exist in the original dataframe but not in the other column I am using to test to.

The code I am using should work, but due to the partial match thing is not and I am stuck.

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  microRNAs                             `number of targets`
  <chr>                                               <int>
1 bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125_3p                        128
2 bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125_5p                          8
3 Dpu-Mir-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p                  44
4 Dpu-Mir-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_5p                  78
5 Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_3p                1076
6 Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_5p                 309

> dput(head(df))
structure(list(microRNAs = c("bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125_3p", 
"bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125_5p", "Dpu-Mir-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p", 
"Dpu-Mir-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_5p", "Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_3p", 
"Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_5p"), `number of targets` = c(128L, 
8L, 44L, 78L, 1076L, 309L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#matches to look for 

             unique
1 miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129
2       LQNS02278139.1_39527
3       LQNS02278139.1_39523
4       LQNS02278075.1_32386
5       Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988

> dput(head(unique))
structure(list(unique = c("miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129", 
"LQNS02278139.1_39527", "LQNS02278139.1_39523", "LQNS02278075.1_32386", 
"Dpu-Mir-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

#Create new column with Yes, No 
df$new <- ifelse(df$microRNAs %in% unique$unique, 'Yes', 'No')

##But it all appears like No due to the partial match.
```

Comment: Can you try with `fuzzyjoin` i.e. `regex_left_join(df, unique, by = c("microRNAs" = "unique"))` or `stringdist_left_join`

Comment: Yay, it works its hacky and good. I thought about a merge too
Can you add it like an answer so I can upvote it?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast solution using `data.table`.

```
    library(data.table)
    
    # convert data.frame to data.table
    setDT(df)
    
    # create temporary column dropping the last 3 characters
    df[, microRNAs_short := substr(microRNAs ,1, nchar(microRNAs)-3) ]
    
    # check values in common
    df[, new := fifelse( microRNAs_short %in% df2$unique, 'Yes', 'No')]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(df, unique, by = c("microRNAs" = "unique"))
```